# Push command creating error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: firebase

I've seen variations of this question in the context of everything from AngularJS to KendoGrid to BackboneJS but all the answers are related to those frameworks and none of them address this directly at a straight-up Firebase level. Since I'm not using any of those, the answers are not helpful to me.

I create the following ref:

```
var loginRef = new Firebase('https://f30s.firebaseio.com/Pablo/pages/login');
```

I try the following push:

```
loginRef.child('clientEvents').push( { Create_account : true } );
```

The push writes to Firebase in the proper directory structure, but console produces the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've ran your code, but I'm not getting any errors. This error occurs when you try to pass a property that is undefined to Firebase. Is there anywhere else where you are sending data to Firebase?

Comment: Since the code snippet above looks fine, the problem is probably in something that you're not showing (yet). Can you set up a reproduction on jsfiddle/jsbin/plunkr?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'll put something together shortly.

Comment: The process of stripping my code to create an example uncovered the problem. It appears my push was triggering another Firebase listener whose event trigger was child_added. That function was trying to parse the string of a value that didn't exist in the child ref.

Comment: ...and I'd set loginRef as a child of that other reference. (I tried to edit the previous comment but hit the five minute limit.)

I'm finding that keeping my refs straight to avoid affecting parent and sibling data is one of the more confusing parts of this. This is all very new to me and I'm learning as I go, so if you know of any references that might make this part of things easier for a noob to understand, I'd really appreciate it. And thanks for your help!